# Android ICS HTTP POST

Tags: android, http-post, android-3.0-honeycomb, ice

I know this question has been asked many times. I have searched the forum as well, but was unable to find the answer I am looking for.

the code works on many android version, but doesnt work on version 3.0 or above.        String response_from_server = null;

```
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(file_n_folder.URL_POST);

    //Log.d("URL",file_n_folder.URL_POST);

    try {

        JSONArray postjson = new JSONArray();
        postjson.put(obj);

        // Post the data:
        httppost.setHeader("json",obj.toString());
        httppost.getParams().setParameter("jsonpost",postjson);

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        // for JSON:
        if(response != null){

            InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String line = null;
            try {
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    is.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            response_from_server = sb.toString();

            //Log.d("RESPONSE FROM SERVER",response_from_server);

            return response_from_server;
        }

    }catch (ClientProtocolException e){
        Log.d("EXCEPTION line 94",e.getMessage());
    }catch (IOException e){
        Log.d("EXCEPTION line 96",e.getMessage());
    }
    return response_from_server;
```

It always crashes the application on httpclient.execute(httppost);

can you guys please suggest me, what or how to fix this?

Thanx

Answer (score 1):

This is because since Honeycomb you are obligated to do your networking outside UI thread. Move your networking to IntentService or AsyncTask

See this article: http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/06/app-force-close-honeycomb-ics.html

Comment: can I see an example of how to achieve this?